# Does assert() act as the identity function in release mode?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, assert

[This library](https://github.com/libbtc/libbtc) uses `assert()` as if it's the identity function in release mode (when NDEBUG is defined). The problem is that some important code is wrapped with `assert()`, and my tests fired when executed in release mode, because these important parts were not called. An example of this can be found [here](https://github.com/libbtc/libbtc/blob/master/src/ecc_key.c#L80), where the random bytes generator will not generate anything and will cause an infinite loop.

Personal anecdote: I dislike `assert()` and I personally don't use it because of these ambiguity issues. I heard of many projects that had serious bugs because of it, most recently EOS, when their unit tests didn't detect some out of range arrays because NDEBUG was defined in release mode and it didn't fire. The documentation doesn't seem to be clear on this point. Does `assert()` act as the identity at all?

This library (libbtc) seems to be used widely, and I don't understand why the developer did this. Is this a horrible mistake and I should fork and remove all these asserts? Or is this some C thing that's not C++ compatible? Could someone please explain the correct course of action here?

I use clang 6.

Comment: `assert` is used to check that situations that can never possibly happen actually never happen. It finds programming errors. If an assert can fail at runtime because of user input or other external factors then it shouldn't have been an assert in the first place.

Comment: There's no ambiguity; the code you've described is simply wrong.

Comment: "I personally don't use it because of these ambiguity issues" - the use of assert is often a team choice.  I know of more than one team that agreed to ship release code with asserts _enabled_.  On at least one system, the asserts became part of the "watch-dog" design.  In one system review, with 3000+ asserts, there were < 20 useless (and harmless) asserts, and none were deemed a problem (they followed the rules).  I seem to remember there were 5 or so rules about asserts.  Something to research?

Comment: Note that an assert that runs in release (and always returns its value) is often called `verify`.  So `if (verify(some_test())){` is a branch that asserts if it fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert :

> If `NDEBUG` is defined as a macro name at the point in the source code where `<cassert>` is included, then assert does nothing.

Do not put anything in `assert` that has side effects you depend on. They won't happen when you compile for release and will alter the behavior of your program.

Comment: So the guy in github messed up. I guess I'll keep the issue I filed there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the library writer misused assert and put functional code where it did not belong.
As far as the bugs because of assert(), it happens because of mis-understanding of its purpose or lack of programming discipline.  assert() is used to verify that invariants do not get broken, not for functional code.  assert() is very easy to mis-use or use in the wrong place.